# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error for a structure member

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have checked the other questions with similar problems, but none of the solutions worked for my case.

The problem in hand is, I am trying to create a stack with dynamic memory, using this struct:

```
struct stekas{
    int content;
    struct stekas *link;
} *top = NULL;
```

However, I'm running into trouble in a few of my functions: Specifically, "Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type". Here's the erroneous pieces of code:

```
struct node *temp;
temp = (struct stekas*)malloc(sizeof(struct stekas));
/* some code */
temp = top;
printf("Popped out number: %d\n", temp->content);
top = top->link;
free(temp);
```

And here's the other function that gets the error:

```
int i;
struct node *temp;
/* some code */
for (i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
printf("%d\n", temp->content[i]);
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the pointer not connecting to the content. I've checked other questions, they seemed to have poblems with the struct itself, but I personally don't see any problems with this one.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Perhaps you want `printf("%d\n", (temp[i]).content);` instead of `printf("%d\n", temp->content[i]);`?

Comment: you seem to assume that `struct node` contains an int array named `content`, but you only shown us the definition of `struct steaks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `struct node` used in these code snippets

```
struct node *temp;
temp = (struct stekas*)malloc(sizeof(struct stekas));
/* some code */
temp = top;
printf("Popped out number: %d\n", temp->content);
top = top->link;
free(temp);
```

and

```
int i;
struct node *temp;
/* some code */
for (i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
printf("%d\n", temp->content[i]);
```

was not defined.

I think you mean `struct stekas`

Also the both code snippets have other serious errors. For example you allocated memory and assigned its addres to pointer `temp`

```
temp = (struct stekas*)malloc(sizeof(struct stekas));
/* some code */
```

and then overwrote the pointer. So the address of the allocated memory is lost.

```
temp = top;
```

So there is a memory leak.

Or in this statement

```
for (i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
```

variable i has type int while top is a pointer. So this assignment i = top and this decreasing i-- does not make sense.

And whet about expression `temp->content[i]` used in the printf statement?

```
printf("%d\n", temp->content[i]);
```

`content` is neither a pointer nor an array. So you may not apply the subscript operator.

Comment: I will admit the code is a mess, and I'm running into more problems, but for the main issue I had, the dereferencing, this answered the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Anstane I advice you to ask new additional questions at SO relative to your project because it seems it contains other problems.

Comment: Erm...should I ask the questions here after editing the main post, or should I search for and then ask a whole new question? Forgive me, I'm still new here, not really aware of proper posting etiquette.

Comment: @Anstane Ask a new question. This question was already answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problems as I see here are

1. `struct node` is not defined is the scope it is used. Maybe `struct node` is meant to be `struct stekas`.
2. `printf("%d\n", temp->content[i]);`

   `content` is not an *array* or *pointer* that can be de-referenced.

That said,

- *usually* it's good practice to check for NULL before dereferencing pointers.
- make sure your `free()` the allocated memory to `temp` before `temp = top;`, to avoid memory leak.

Also, please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = top;
```

`top` is null and you are making `temp` point to null and dereference it which will lead to undefined behavior.

You `malloc()` would have given you memory which you can access so use it.

Comment: The cut code in both cases merely checks if top = NULL and if so, says that the stack is empty.

Comment: @Anstane Deferencing a null pointer leads to undefined behavior

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong, but the problem you mentioned should not result a compiler error.